# Ischemia-induced deploarization in excitable cells

Tags: molecular-biology, physiology, neurophysiology, electrophysiology, action-potential

I have read in many sources that ischemia-induced depolarization is due to the opening of ATP-sensitive potassium channels and inactivation of Na/K exchangers [[1](https://journals.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/advan.00105.2016),[2](https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/10.1161/01.RES.80.1.124)]. However, K-atp channels are inward-rectifiers and their extensive opening should cause extracellular hypokalemia besides the fact that in low [ATP]i during ischemia, Mg++ ions are free (not complexed with ATP), and magnesium ions are outward potassium current blockers (i,e, they increase the rectifying power of k-atp, Kir, K-Ach channels)[[3](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphys.2018.01077/full),[4](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0006295289902724?via%3Dihub)]. this would cause extracellular hypokalemic depolarization. What is the source of hyperkalemia then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inward-rectifying means positive current passes more easily in the inward direction, however it won't flow differently than the membrane voltage and reversal potential dictate. See for example https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inward-rectifier_potassium_channel

The only time you'll have potassium flowing in to a cell, rather than out, is if the cell is very hyperpolarized, beyond the reversal potential for potassium, which is more negative than the resting potential.

Open potassium channels will almost always reduce intracellular potassium concentration as potassium flows out of the cell. Without ATP to fuel the sodium-potassium pump, there's no way to restore the lost potassium.

The existence of a negative resting membrane potential is due to relative concentrations of potassium (high inside cells) and the existence of primarily potassium conductance in the membrane, which means a few positive ions leak out to make the inside negative. If you don't maintain that concentration gradient, the cell is going to depolarize.

Comment: I'd also suggest an honorable mention of the chloride anions that stayed within the membrane in the last graph.

Comment: i will try to explain what i understood. So, when the K+ channels open during repolarization the permeability is so high that according to goldmann's equation the resting membrane potential (RMP) is closer to K+ reversal potential(hyperpolarization) But as repolarization ends the fast and slow rectifyer channels close so the RMP shifts to a more positive voltage and then K-leak channels and K1 (inward rectifyer) channels open and since they are not as abunduntly opened as the channels during repolarization.........

Comment: ..... the RMP is still more positive than it was at end of repolarization. this causes the correction of RMP to the pre-depolarization state. So the main function of K1 is to allow rapid influx of k+ ions to correct hyperpolarization as fast as possible and thne k+ leak channels maintain their efflux. Am I right?

Comment: @kljiuklk1 Unless the membrane voltage is more negative than the potassium reversal potential (which can never happen by potassium flowing alone, no matter what channels are open), potassium net flow is always out of the cell. There's no "rapid influx of potassium ions". Leak channels are always open. Recovery from hyperpolarization happens because other ions (mostly sodium) are leaking in faster than potassium is leaking out.

Comment: @BryanKrause, but if that is the case then why the correction of hyperpolarization is attributed to K1 channels. And why would there be an inward rectifyer if potassium is always flowing out even at hyperpolarized state?

Comment: @kljiuklk1 Mostly those channels can be thought of to be somewhat self-closing when cells *depolarize*, which allows for cells to both have more "leak-like" current at rest, making them less susceptible to "accidental"/random depolarizing events, yet not interfere with the depolarizing current which is metabolically costly if you have lots of sodium and potassium flowing against each other.

Comment: It's somewhat random luck that at severely hyperpolarized potentials those channels are *even more* conductive, but those conditions only occur artificially.

Comment: Note also that "inward-rectifying" is just the direction of the rectification... The function continues in that direction within the physiological range where potassium is always flowing out, it's just that there is a higher conductance when closer to rest and lower conductance when further depolarized.

Comment: I cannot think of a non-artificial circumstance in which a typical neuron or muscle cell would have a potential more negative than potassium reversal. Im not sure where you've gotten the idea that they are responsible for "correction of hyperpolarization" outside of artificial circumstances.

Comment: so if i understand correctly inward-rectifier is another way of saying weak (semi-closed on efflux) K+ channels (i,e, it allows the membrane to reach the point of RMP according to goldmann equation but at less permeabilty and slow rate (slow K+ efflux) ). If we were to remove the rectifier function of these channels, the RMP will decrease because non-rectifier channel is more permeable to K+efflux .right?

Comment: @kljiuklk1 I wouldn't think of them as weak, either, actually I don't know what their overall single channel conductance is, but it need not related to the presence of rectification. Rectifying is a relative thing. It's mainly that they are just most permeable closer to resting potential, so they help maintain resting potential without interfering with spikes as much.

Comment: So, inward rectification is just an identification property rather than a functional property (at normal physiological level) and if inward-rectification of a channel increases this means in the other way around that outward-rectification K+ effllux decreased and thus its conductance decreases. as inward rectification can be increased by increasing [Mg]i which according to some research blocks the outward-rectifier portion of the gate and thus the cell will b emore depolarized.

Comment: @kljiuklk1 No. I'm sorry, my patience for this has run out. Read to what I am writing, read about these channels in more than one reputable source, and don't keep trying to add on your own meaning to things or inventing terms like "outward rectification decreased". Channels are what channels are. If you lose potassium channels, of any type that have any open probability at rest, the resting potential will be less negative. You can test this out using the Goldman equation.